# Select elements other then a specific one form Xml Object

Tags: php, xml, parsing

I am parsing the array given below. Looping through td using foreach. Now i want to select the value other than [@attributes]. I cannot use a or p specifically as they change through out the objects.

How can i achieve this?

```
[0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [th] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [@attributes] => Array
                    (
                        [rowspan] => 2
                        [scope] => row
                    )

                [p] => Memory
            )

        [td] => Array
            (
                [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [@attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [class] => ttl
                            )

                        [a] => Card slot
                    )

                [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [@attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [class] => nfo
                            )

                        [p] => No
                    )

            )

    )
```

Want the solution to work in php.

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: It is simpley a for loop. foreach($td as $element)

Comment: But here it shows that you're traversing Simple XML Object too. If you show your partial working code then it would be better for anyone to sort it out easily

Comment: td is also an attribute of Simple Xml Object. So looping through the xml object. I have modified the question for you.

Comment: Are `a` and `p` will always be there? Means will be there other key possible in addition with `a` and `p`?

Comment: NO they will change, that is the only problem, otherwise i would have used static references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below one

```
<?php
foreach($td as $element)
{
    foreach($element as $key => $value)
    {
        if(!preg_match("/@/", $key) && !is_array($value))
            echo $element[$key];
    }
}
?>
```